# Is there a benefit from "S4 Doze to Hibernate"?

Tags: windows-10, sleep, hibernate

[image]

Above is how Windows 10 changed the power plan after an update. If I put the laptop to sleep, it now **wakes up to hibernate** after 3 hours. Is there any benefit? `S4 Doze to Hibernate` is what it's called in the event viewer.

It's explained [here](http://mikeberggren.com/post/113733489241/wake-up) and asked about here:

[Windows 10 Desktop wakes from sleep to hibernate even when disabled](https://superuser.com/questions/1127988/windows-10-desktop-wakes-from-sleep-to-hibernate-even-when-disabled?rq=1)

My question, is it beneficial to leave it as it is? After all Microsoft decided to have it for some reason.

Comment: You can't put in a hibernate state and a sleep state

Comment: Sleep takes battery power hibernate does not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If asleep there is a small power use, and small potential to lose data not saved to disk if power is lost.

If hibernated, all data is saved to disk, and no power is required.

Microsoft seem to be assuming that if you haven't come back after 3 hours then maybe you've gone to bed or forgotten the computer, and the reduced power and data loss potential of hibernate would be to your benefit. If you left the computer at work on over the weekend, maybe this behaviour is a benefit.

If you have an SSD, or SSD cache, the computer wakes from hibernate rapidly, and so in these cases there is little time lost hibernating - so the benefit may  outweigh the negative (ie increased time to awake).

Of course, if you are running any kind of server, or modelling simulation you won't want it to hibernate. Or if you have 16+ gig of ram and no SSD cache, you'll be waiting a while to wake from hibernate. Or if you have a laptop  or desktop with UPS then you won't worry about power outages so much. So whether it is beneficial will vary between users.